# Python: Saving email with Russian characters to TXT file

Tags: python, email, encoding

I tried to save email with Cyrillic characters to the TXT file. The email is also generate automatically. Here is complete code of the function:

```
def send_and_archive_email(self):

        #connect to mailbox
        smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        smtpObj.starttls()
        login = input('Please, enter your login: ')
        password = input('Please, enter you password: ')
        smtpObj.login(login, password)

        header, body = self.draft_email() # return tuple of strings with Cyrillic characters
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = header
        msg['From'] = **********
        msg['To'] = *********
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8'))

        for name in self.cioms_names:
            with open(self.folder/name, "rb") as fil:
                part = MIMEApplication(
                    fil.read(),
                    Name=name
                )
            part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(name)
            msg.attach(part)

        smtpObj.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
        smtpObj.quit()

        #archive email and delivery confirmation
        connection = self.connect_to_email('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')
        search_criteria = **************    
        email_id = self.search_emails('SUBJECT', search_criteria, connection)
        typ, message = connection.fetch(email_id[0], '(RFC822)')
        raw = email.message_from_bytes(message[0][1])

        for part in raw.walk():

            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue


            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                filepath = self.folder/"test_save.txt"

                with codecs.open(filepath, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                    body = u'' + part.get_payload()
                    file.write(body)
```

The text is saved into the file in weird format. I know that this is encoding problem and tried some popular ones like utf-8, windows-1251, but the problem is not solved. Any thoughts or suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Which Python version do you use?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, Python 3.7

Comment: You can try to write a string with some Cyrillic characters to the beginning of the file to see how they are shown in the text editor. Also you can print() a part of the body to see if that works. And you can play around with the settings of the text editor to check if it just processes the file wrongly.